# CSV and Excel Advanced File Properties

Tags: excel, vba

Looking around there are many examples on how use VBA to populate a listbox in Excel with the files found in a folder, filtering for files based on criteria.

My first question is it possible to filter files based on their advanced properties such as Category / Comments etc?

The second question is it possible to amend the advanced properties from within Excel using VBA without opening them?

I am not looking for someone to write the VBA (although I admit I may need some help in the future if I get stuck) but rather if the concept is feasible. What difficulties may be encountered or things to avoid etc.

Thanks